# 2-parter; in Javascript - detect special chars and replace all * with %

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, character

Question 1: I've tried the following to detect characters (uppercase and lowercase), numbers and * but I am getting an error that it's not a valid regular expression.

```
var pattern = '?[a-zA-Z0-9*][a-zA-Z0-9*]*';
```

Question 2: How can I replace all instances of a * character with a % character in a string with a regular expression? I'm a regex noob and everything I've tried so far keeps bombing...
(Answered)

Edit 1 & 2: Clarification of my lunacy.

Edit 3: Wanted to provide my final solution:

This is what I ended up with for my pattern matching:

```
var pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9*]*$";
var regEx = new RegExp(pattern);
if(regEx.test(searchText) === true) {
    return true;
}
```

The selected answer below does the replacement as I initially asked for. Thank you all for your answers and help.

Comment: Perhaps you could post what you have tried so that someone can tell you why it failed and how to fix it.

Comment: was just editting my question with that info.

Comment: I'm confused -- the pattern that you've just added seems completely unrelated to the initial question.

Comment: * is a special character in a regular expression, so you need to escape it with a leading backslash when you mean "the asterisk character".

Comment: @sblom Not inside character class brackets `[]`, although I'm not convinced I understand where the OP intended the `*` to be.

Comment: So is the posted pattern valid if checking inputs for only upper/lowercase characters, digits (0-9) and an * (asterisk)?

Comment: @DaveNewton - the asterisk is valid anywhere in the input

Comment: @acedanger Irrelevant to the point I was making to sblom, and not really important for your question, either, at least as I understand it, if your goal is to actually replace `*` with `%`. What's your real question? Detecting only letters/numbers, or replacing `*` with `%`?

Comment: @ruakh and DaveNewton you're right, I was attempting to detect the presence of upper/lowercase chars, digits 0-9 and * in user input (hence the pattern I posted). When I tested my code I noticed the error (not a valid reg ex).

Comment: first character of my pattern is wrong. the ? should be a ^....not sure why the ? is there. I'm not _that_ slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newString = "foo*bar*baz".replace(/\*/g, "%");
```

The `g` regex flag means "globally", or "all of 'em".

Comment: Thanks for reading my mind and answering an unasked question. (That sounds sarcastic, it's not - it's sincere)

Answer (score 5):

This question frightens me, because it suggests that you're creating a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability, but the answer is:

```
s = 'foo*bar*baz';
s = s.replace(/\*/g, '%');
// now s == 'foo%bar%baz'
```

Comment: It's as though everyone uses the same meta-syntactic variables.

Comment: I understand the concern, but I'm trying to test for characters prior to replacing anything.

Answer (score 1):

**Answering the "Question 1" part**

First, if you want to define a regex pattern to use elsewhere, it is done with slashes `/` not quotes `"` e.g.

```
/?[a-zA-Z0-9*][a-zA-Z0-9*]*/
```

This is *not* a valid regular expression, because the "optional" `?` operator needs something to its left to operate on, just like `*` does. Removing that does give you a valid regex.

```
var pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9*][a-zA-Z0-9*]*/;
```

Improvements - since your two character classes `[a-zA-Z0-9*]` are exactly the same, you don't have to repeat them, just use the `+` operator instead of `*`

```
var pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9*]+/;
```

and rather than list `a-zA-Z` just ignore case by appending the operator `i`

```
var pattern = /[A-Z0-9*]+/i;
```

Finally, if you want to test the input exactly matches, you need to anchor the pattern at both the start and end, otherwise `.match()` will find the pattern if it appears anywhere in the input.

```
var pattern = /^[A-Z0-9*]+$/i;
var input = "Foo*Bar*baz";
console.log("Got: " + input.match(pattern);
```

Comment: Thank you for stepping through each step. I really appreciate it.